# Is there a way to make a keyboard shortcut for Save on the node edit page?

Tags: nodes

It would save a lot of time not having to scroll to the bottom of the page to save edits to a node.

Are there modules which achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Keyboard Shortcut](https://drupal.org/project/keyboard_shortcut) module might be the one you are looking for , Project page says

> The Keyboard Shortcut Utility module enables you to create keyboard
>   shortcuts on your website. You can create a shortcut to go to a page
>   (internal or external) or call a JavaScript function.

Comment: Can you advise which JavaScript function is called to achieve a node save?

Comment: I believe you need to write a Javascript function to click on node save submit when you are on node edit / create page and associate that function with Keyboard Shortcut using above module. Project page also says "To create a key binding, go to Configuration and click on "Keyboard shortcuts"."

Comment: I was hoping for a contrib module to provide this functionality in full, but it appears one does not exist. Thanks for your answer Anil.

Answer (score 1):

[Hotkeys for Save](https://www.drupal.org/project/hotkeys_for_save) module allow to use keyboard shortcut for Save on the node edit page:

> Do you often edit content or other site data? Do you get tired of
>   scrolling endless down to the Save button? If so, this module allows
>   you to use hotkeys Ctrl+S (Win) and Cmd+S (Mac) instead of clicking on
>   the Save button.

Comment: Are you the author of this module?  Promoting your own module for a solution is fine, but we typically prefer users to acknowledge when it is their own module.